# Fragment usando AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou obtendo esse erro:

> onPrepareOptionsMenu Menu in android.support.v4.app.Fragment clashes with onPrepareOptions Menu Menu in android.app.Activity attemping to use incompatible return type.

[image: inserir a descrição do link aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, mostre a implantação do método onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: Quando Implemento esse Metodo aparece esse erro **getLoaderManager() in android.support.v4.app.Fragment clashes with getLoaderManager() in android.app.Activity attemptimg to use incompatible return type**.... mesmo implementando  **@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    }** fica pedido para colocar return boolean e quando mudo pede para colocar void parecendo estar em conflito e que estou tentando implementar um slidershow com Lib AndroidImageSlider dentro de um fragmento que esta dentro de um Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Fica difícil te ajudar sem você postar o.codigo. Na imagem que você postou, sua classe está herdando de fragment e de AppCompatActivity e isso não é possível, pois no Java não existe herança múltipla. Posta si a implementação do método com erro para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Postei outro print Removi o AppCompatActivity ao fazer isso aparece esses erros ...a implementação **onPrepareOptionsMenu** deu certo, estava em duvida sobre isso mesmo.

Comment: @LeonardoMarques os construtores esperam um context como parâmetro. Onde tem InicioFragment.this você pode alterar para getActivity() assim deve funcionar.

Comment: java tem herança múltipla sim mas vc so faz isso com Interfaces

Comment: @JasarOrion correto

Comment: @JasarOrion verdade, na verdade não sei se implementar várias interfaces pode ser considerado herança. De acordo com este post http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/multiple-inheritance/, herança é a habilidade de herdar de várias classes e de acordo com o próprio post, já não faz isso. Mas como vc falou: você pode implementar várias interfaces.